# Modeling the importance of data points in Logistic Regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, categorical-data

Given N data points where each entry of a point represents a value of a feature, and we need to use this data to model a binary Logistic regression model.
e.g. lets say the data points represents MNIST dataset.

Is there a way to determine which data points are important for the model?

As an inspiration, consider the following example:

We have 100 point where each point is composed of two values, i.e. two features.
99 of the points were the given 0 as a label where 1 of the points was given 1 as a label.
Clearly, the point which have the label of 1 is crucial for the model so we need to take this point seriously so that the model will guarantee better results.

The sample size can be any number bigger than 0 and lower or equal to N.

The objective is to sample the data points so that crucial points will be chosen rather than choosing uniformly!

To conclude, the goal of the analysis is to sample all the points that are crucial for the model i.e. if you do not take them into account then your model is inappropriate or incorrect.
e.g. look at the example provided above, if you don't take the only point which it's label is 1 then your model will always miss such points (points which their label is 1).

Please advise and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide context. For example, where does the data come from, how many variables are available, what is the sample size, and what is the overall goal of the analysis?

Comment: Is it ok now? i mean is it more clear than before?

Comment: No, I still have no idea what, e.g., the goal of the analysis is. It might be helpful to read [this](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/how-can-we-encourage-askers-to-provide-context), [this](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/), or [this](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated/1483#1483).

Comment: the goal of the analysis is to sample all the points that are crucial for the model i.e. if you do not sample them then your model is inappropriate or incorrect.